# Algorithm to count line numbers with "mixed newline types"

Tags: parsing, newline

I need a specific description (a description that is not too obfuscated by something like a regular expression, etc.) for an algorithm that can count, say, a source file with mixed newlines:

```
'\r', '\n', '\r\n', '\n\r'
```

I have the following algorithm currently. Is it OK?:

1. I make sure to always be on the "boundary" of the first newline-type character.
2. On that event, I compare the current byte character.

3.1. If it is '\n', I count it as ending the current line and starting a new line.

3.2. If it is '\r', I read the next character (if not beyond the limit of the text buffer) and see if it is '\n'. If it is, I count it as a '\r\n' newline.

3.3. If it is '\r', and the next character is NOT '\n', I count it as a newline produced by '\r'; mark the current line as ended and count it as the start of a new line.

---

If it is useful, I need it to try to produce greater "portability" on source files that are copy/pasted across web browsers, and/or appended from several files that have different types of newlines, and I have parsing tools that I want to make sure will have a correct and robust behavior in all cases.

Comment: If your question is "is this algorithm OK?", then yes, it is perfectly reasonable, and the most straight-forward way of attacking this problem (IMO).

Comment: You really should learn what a regular expression is.  What you just did was "compile" the regular expression to a finite state machine.

Comment: @KristopherMicinski - because he stated he didn't want to use a RE for this approach, it's reasonable to assume he knows what REs are, and is choosing (or someone is choosing for him) not to use them.

Comment: But he _did_ use a regular expression.  He implemented a finite state machine.  Whether he calls it a regular expression or not, he implemented something which generates a regular expression, and using one would have compiled down to this implementation for any optimized RE implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That algorithm should cover 99.999% of all cases.

You should probably read the source in binary mode rather than text mode, to make sure there isn't an I/O layer trying to help you by converting some of these to `'\n'`.

You didn't specify which language you're working in.  Note that in C and C++, `'\n'` is different from other escape characters in that it's not guaranteed to have a particular value.  It's true that in most implementations, it will map to ASCII linefeed, but it's safer and more explicit to use something like `'\x0A'` to keep your code portable.

There have been a few other schemes for newlines, but they are extremely rare.  There's a [NEL](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/85/index.htm) character in Unicode that's for round-trip compatibility with files that were originally in EBCDIC (I think).  Unicode also introduced [LINE SEPARATOR](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/index.htm) and [PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2029/index.htm), which you might want to treat as line break characters as well.  But those are extremely rare and can be complicated to handle because they're outside the ASCII range and thus you need to know your encoding and be ready to deal with those issues.